# What is the difference between these two methods? JAVA

Tags: java, methods, roman-numerals

My prof provided me with a bunch of methods to fill in for a roman numeral program (in additive format, so 4=IIII, 9=VIIII, etc.)

I'm having trouble understanding what the difference is between these two methods:

```
   **
   * This method prints, to the standard output and in purely additive
   * notation, the Roman numeral corresponding to a natural number.
   * If the input value is 0, nothing is printed. This
   * method must call the method romanDigitChar(). 
   * @param val   ?
   */

    public void printRomanNumeral(int val)
    {

    }

   **
   * This method returns the Roman numeral digit corresponding
   * to an integer value. You must use a nested-if statement.
   * This method cannot perform any arithmetic operations. 
   * @param val  ?
   * @return     ?
   */

    public char romanDigitChar(int val)

    {

    }
```

Is romanDigitChar supposed to read a number digit by digit, and only return one digit at a time? If so, I don't understand how printRomanNumeral would go about calling it.

I've researched other roman numeral programs, but I can't seem to find any that use methods called within other methods like this one that I could compare it to.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: This question seems more appropriate to ask your professor.

Comment: True, but I want to do some work on it now, and it's Sunday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume romanDigitChar returns one char for an exact matching numbers e.g. 1, 5, 10, 50, 100 etc only. printRomanNumeral would call this repeatedly for known values as numbers to turn them into characters. I suggest two nested loops, one for amounts with specific characters in decreasing value and one extracting each value. The inner loop calls the second method.

I assume he/she expects ASCII characters although there are special Unicode characters for Roman numerals.

Comment: So for romanDigitChar I could do something like: if (val < 5) {someString = someString + I} etc?

Comment: No, because then the return type either wouldn't be a char (it would be string), or it would be pointless, because someString would be a global variable. The idea is that you return a char each time, not that you were asking me.

Comment: Ohhhh, so it will do it char by char. The outer method will have to call it a bunch of times then for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, romanDigitchar returns a char (the Roman Numeral corresponding to the natural number given as input). printRomanNumeral doesn't return anything, but is supposed to print the Roman numeral.

Answer (score 0):

`Is romanDigitChar supposed to read a number digit by digit, and only return one digit at a time?` Yes, for instance if you want to print two roman numeral digits: IIII, VIIII. In your 
`void printRomanNumeral(int val)`method,you need to do:

```
public void printRomanNumeral(int val)
{
         System.out.println(romanDigitChar(4));
         System.out.println(romanDigitChar(9));          
}
```

But in your `char romanDigitChar(int val)` method, you need to have some sorts of algorithm to convert natural number to roman number, something like:

```
    public char romanDigitChar(int val)
    {

        if(val == 4) {
          //Return a roman digit 4.
        }
        if(val == 9) {
          //Return a roman digit 9.
        }

      }
```

Comment: The romanDigitChar says `This method cannot perform any arithmetic operations. `

Comment: There is NO single char that represents value of 4, nor there is one for value of 9...

Comment: @GermannArlington I provided a hint to him. Do you think is gonna be a good idea if i give exact answer to him since this is an assignment.

Comment: But the hint is wrong. The method returns single char. To represent 4 (IV) in roman, it will need 2 chars.

Comment: @MinGW What you provided was the answer and the incorrect answer at that. Considering that ANY number (with exception of zero) can be represented by one or more Roman numerals it is logical to assume that romanDigitChar(int val) should accept ONLY the numbers that have exact single Roman numeral representation. I.e. you can call it with one of the values = {1,5,10,50,...} but nothing else. Otherwise the method will have NO WAY to determine what needs to be returned.

Comment: @GermannArlington I completely understand your point. But I dont think you get my point, when I said:" `Return a roman digit 4`" DOESN'T mean return a char which represents a real roman number. Instead, returning matching numbers 4 or 9 in my case. Then in `void printRomanNumeral(int val)`, you need to convert them into real roman number and print.